Optimizing for the “under the river cost”
Suppose an oil refinery is located on the north bank of a $2$ km wide river, $6$ km west of storage tanks located on the south bank of the river, to which pipelines are to be constructed from the refinery. Suppose further that the cost of running pipeline over land is $\$400,000$/km to a point $P$ on the north bank, and the cost of running pipeline under the river is considerably higher than the cost of laying pipe over land. I want to show that no matter what this “under the river” cost $k$ is, it will not be cheaper to take $P$ to be directly across from the storage tanks at $6$ km.
Assuming $x$ is the distance on the north bank to the left of $P$ and $6-x$ is the distance of pipe over land from the refinery, then if $4$ and $k$ are in hundreds of thousands of dollars we get that the cost function is:$$C(x)=4(6-x)+k\sqrt{x^2+4}, \quad0\leq x\leq 6$$ which implies $$C’(x)=\frac{-4\sqrt{x^2+4}+kx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=0\implies x = \frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}$$
Thus $$C(0)=24+2k$$ $$C(6)=k\sqrt{40}=2k\sqrt{10}$$ $$C\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}\right)=24-\frac{32}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}+\frac{2k^2}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}$$
As I see it there are a few problems here. First off, $x = 8/\sqrt{k^2-16}$ is not less than $6$ for all $k>4$ and even if it is, how does one show $C(8/\sqrt{k^2-16})$ is less than $C(0)$ and $C(6)$ analytically?
Very similar to this question; the diagram used there is similar to the one needed in this problem.
This is problem $66$ in Stewart’s Calculus, in the optimization section. We are not prompted to use a graphing calculator or CAS.

Your observation that $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}$ is in the interval of allowable $x,,$ namely $[0,6]$ for large enough $k,,$ is totally correct. Show that $C(x)$ has an absolute minimum there, and reconsider if it is true what you wanted to show no matter what $k$ is. In modern times it is masochistic not to use a graphing calculator. This does not mean you have to use it in the solution you are submitting.

Hopefully someone will let me know if this reasoning is correct.
Note that $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}<6\implies \sqrt{k^2-16}>8/6\implies k^2>160/9\implies$ $$k>\frac{4\sqrt{10}}{3}$$
Then observe that $$C(0)=24+2k$$ $$C\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}\right)=24+\frac{2k^2-32}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}=24+2\sqrt{k^2-16}<24+2k$$ $$C(6)= 2k\sqrt{10}$$
So if $4<k<4\sqrt{10}/3$ then $x>6$ and $$0<k^2-16< 16/9\implies0<2\sqrt{k^2-16}<8/3\implies24< C\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}\right) <80/3$$ and $$32<C(0)<8\sqrt{10}/3+24$$ $$8\sqrt{10}<C(6)<80/3$$
But the critical point $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}$ being greater than $6$ is nonsensical as it adds distance and unneeded cost by necessity; so we consider the endpoints where we see $C(6)<C(0)$ so that $x=6$ minimizes the cost in this case.
When $k=4\sqrt{10}/3$, we see $6=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}$ so that $C(6)= C(8/\sqrt{k^2-16}) = 2k\sqrt{10}=80/3$ hence the path with $x=6$ or diagonally across the river from the refinery to the storage tanks should be chosen. For $k>4\sqrt{10}/3$ and thus $x<6$, we see since $2k\sqrt{10}$ grows faster than $2\sqrt{k^2-16}<2k$ we conclude $$C\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}\right) < C(0)$$ $$C\left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{k^2-16}}\right) <C(6)$$ so that $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}<6$ minimizes the cost.
So I believe the conclusion I’m supposed to now draw is that no matter what $k>4$ is, the path of least cost will never necessarily be to travel to directly across the storage tanks on the opposite bank and then under the river.
We say necessarily here because in case $k=4\sqrt{10}/3$, either the path directly under the river from the refinery to the storage tanks or the path to directly across from the storage tanks on the opposite bank and under the river — minimizes cost.
However, problem $66$ in Stewart claims never:

You may suspect that in some instances, the minimum distance possible under the river should be used, and $P$ should be located $6$ km from the refinery, directly across from the storage tanks. Show that this is never the case, no matter what the “under river” cost is.

But I seem to have found a counterexample to “never” by finding that this path does minimize the cost when $k=4\sqrt{10}/3>4.$ Is this an error in the wording of the problem?

No. Wait. Draw a picture of the situation at the river. Hint: when we want the minimum distance to be used under the river we have (in your notation for $C(x)$) that the optimal $x$ must be zero. Is that ever the case when $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16},?$

Technically it isn't wrong. Since "P should be located..." means that it is neccessary to put the point at that position, but you can always choose a different location. That also agrees with OP's wording that "it will not be cheaper to take $P$ directly..."

@KurtG. I think I’ve fixed the problem. For $k=4\sqrt{10}/3$, we have that $6=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}$ so that $C(6)=C(8/\sqrt{k^2-16})=80/3$ which is less than $C(0)$, so $x=6$ minimizes the cost. The same conclusion is drawn for $4<k<4\sqrt{10}/3$.

Yes. But Stewart wants you to realize that there is no finite $k$ that makes $x$ exactly zero.

Well that’s fine I agree but then we always have to consider the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=6$, but I’m not exactly sure how I concluded that $x=0$ was a cost minimizing path last night. I must’ve thought $x=8/\sqrt{k^2-16}=0$, alas your comment.

So in other words, Stewart’s wording is exactly correct since no matter what $k>4$ is, $x=0$ is never a cost minimizing path.
